# MySQL: join 3 tables and select an identical row as alias

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I want to join 3 tables in something like the following manner:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tableC AS c ON a.id = c.id
WHERE
b.name = c.name OR b.name IS NULL OR c.name IS NULL;
```

I can't be sure, that table b or c will have a row to join, but if both have a row to join, the name column must be identical.

My question is: I want to select this name column, but I only want to select it once. So, if b and c have a row to join, I want the name from either of them, If just one has a row to join, I want the name of that row. 
The column name in the result should be in each case identical.

Table examples

tableA

```
 id 
---- 
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

tableB

```
 id | name
----|------
  2 |  X
  3 |  Y
```

tableC

```
 id | name
----|------
  2 |  Q
  3 |  Y
  4 |  Z
```

desired result:

```
 id | name
----|------
  1 | (NULL)
  2 |  X       (name is from tableB) 
  2 |  Q       (name is from tableC)
  3 |  Y       (name is from tableB or tableC)
  4 |  Z       (name is from tableC)
```

Comment: tableB is mentioned twice.

Comment: thanks, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, IFNULL(b.name, c.name)
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tableC AS c ON a.id = c.id
WHERE
b.name = c.name OR b.name IS NULL OR c.name IS NULL;
```

This query should return what you want. `IFNULL(X, Y)` works by saying if X is null, then use Y. With your example, if b.name is not null, b.name will be shown. If b.name is null, then c.name will be shown. If something is in c.name, then the name will be printed, but if c.name is null `NULL` will be shown as you desired.

Comment: Yeah - your statement is correct. I retract the comment. ;-)

Comment: I need the where statement, as it is possible, that there are multiple identical ids with different names and this should than be matched on the name

Comment: Multiple identical ids with different names seems to go against your statement of "... but if both have a row to join, the name column must be identical." I may not be understanding though, so an example of this or reference to where it appears in your question would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the example (note id: 2 with name: Q in tableC). The ids are actally timestamps, so its possible that there are multiple identical timestamps with different names

Comment: I edited my answer with the condition added in. You shouldn't need to have to check if either name is null with the `IFNULL` in place, but you can add them in if necessary of course.

Comment: problem no is, that with the where clause in place, just rows are fetched where tableB and tableC are set (and name is identical).

Comment: I put back in your `WHERE` in my answer. I had misunderstood your preconditions when initially answering.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
  (CASE COALESCE(b.`name`, '') WHEN '' THEN c.`name` ELSE b.`name` END) AS name2,
  b.`name` AS B,
  c.`name` AS C
FROM foo1 AS a
LEFT JOIN foo2 AS b ON (a.id = b.id)
LEFT JOIN foo3 AS c ON (a.id = c.id)
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, would be best to get rid of LEFT at all, if not necessary.

```
SELECT a.id, b.name
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT a.id, c.name
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableC AS c ON a.id = c.id
```

if you don't want the rows where name is NULL, remove LEFT